# How Can I Set An Environment Variable Inside "bin" Field of "package.json"

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, environment-variables, npm-install

I have an npm package that has a cli:

```js
  "bin": {
    "myprogram": "./cli.js"
  }
```

It is executable by running `myprogram --param value` with no problem.
I couldn't find it in [npm's docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) but I wonder if there is an approach to set an environment variable before running `cli.js`

I've tried:

```js
  "bin": {
    "myprogram": "TZ=utc ./cli.js"
  }
```

but looks like npm doesn't handle it:

```sh
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@myprogram/myprogram/TZ=utc ./cli.js
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@myprogram/myprogram/TZ=utc ./cli.js'
```

I don't want to do this by `TZ=utc myprogram`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot set environment variables the way you are hoping, but I can suggest an alternative solution.

In your package.json set the scripts field to:

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "TZ=utc ./cli.js"
}
```

Then create a file in the same folder as cli.js, lets call it cli-wrapper.js.

You can then create cli-wrapper.js with the following snippet:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const started = spawn('npm', ['run', 'start'], { cwd: __dirname });

started.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout:', data.toString());
});

started.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr:', data.toString());
});

started.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code:', code.toString());
});
```

The above snippet is a small piece of code that simply spawns a node script process in the current directory using 'npm run script'. <strike>You may need to make some adjustments to this snippet depending on how you are running the bin file. Maybe use [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) to resolve the correct directory and change to it before issuing the command.</strike> I don't believe adjusting the directory is necessary anymore, I have adjusted the above code and it seems to be functioning as expected.

Then you can adjust your package.json file's bin parameter:

```js
"bin": {
  "myprogram": "./cli-wrapper.js"
}
```

And as long as the spawn snippet runs in the correct folder it should allow you to specify different environment parameters within the scripts.start field in your package.json.

Comment: That's a reasonable answer. I'm currently using other standart ways of setting env vars but thanks anyway.